# Does the >>= operator not take a function?

Tags: f#, hopac

I'm working on a side project and I'm using Hopac for the first time.  I ran into an odd (to me) compilation issue that I haven't been able to grok.  I suspect that I'm the problem here, and not Hopac.

The program is supposed to be a simple console app that consumes notifications from various services.  Here's the problematic module:

```
module Provider

open System
open System.IO
open Hopac
open BitThicket.NotificationHelper.Core
open BitThicket.NotificationHelper.Providers

let defaultProviderTypes =
    [| typeof<GitHub.GitHubNotificationProvider> |]

type Provider = {
    getCh : Ch<Providers.INotification seq>
}

let giveLatest ch latest =
    Ch.give 

let start config logger (providerType:Type) = Job.delay <| fun () ->
    let providerImpl = Activator.CreateInstance(providerType) :?> Providers.INotificationProvider
    let p = { getCh = Ch() }

    let rec server = 
        let latest = providerImpl.GetLatestNotificationsAsync(None) |> Job.fromAsync 
        latest >>= Ch.give p.getCh // error here
    }

    Job.start server
```

In this case, the compiler complains: `Expecting a type supporting the operator '>>=' but given a function type. You may be missing an argument to a function.`

Similarly, if I use a slightly different syntax:

```
// ...
    let rec server =
        let latest = providerImpl.GetLatestNotificationsAsync(None) |> Job.fromAsync
        latest >>= fun l -> Ch.give p.getCh l // error here
// ...
```

In this case, the error is: `This function takes too many arguments, or is used in a context where a function is not expected.`

I asked haf about his in slack, and his suggestion was to check for alternative definitions of `>>=`.  The tooling doesn't really do much to help me figure that one out, but the only namespace/module I have opened that defines `>>=` is `Hopac` (the `BitThicket` ones are just trivially simple namespaces with some type definitions in them).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm looking at the source code, and I see that the bind operator is actually defined in [`Hopac.Infixes`](https://github.com/Hopac/Hopac/blob/master/Libs/Hopac/Hopac.fs#L184), not in `Hopac`.

Comment: Oh, good golly.  I just assumed it was `AutoOpen`, but you're totally right.  Thanks!  I'd suggest moving your comment to an answer so you can pick up some fake internet points! :-)

Comment: Ok, done, converted to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm looking at the source code, and I see that the bind operator is actually defined in [`Hopac.Infixes`](https://github.com/Hopac/Hopac/blob/master/Libs/Hopac/Hopac.fs#L184), not in `Hopac`.